# Protection level error in dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm getting this error message "Inaccessible due to its protection level" in the last line but I've checked and everything seems to be public. What could be wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class Sneakers
    {

        public string _brand;
        public Sneakers(string brand)
        {
            _brand = brand;
        }
        public string Show()
        {
            return "The brand is: " + _brand;
        }
        public static string Show(Sneakers mySneak)
        {
            return mySneak.Show();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Sneakers mySneak = new Sneakers("Nike");

            Dictionary<Sneakers, double> collection = new Dictionary<Sneakers, double>();
            collection.Add(mySneak, 10);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<Sneakers, double> item in collection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Sneakers.Show(item.key));//HERE IS THE ERROR IN "key"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume it's because `key` is a private field. You want `Key`.

Comment: For sake of god just make that `k` uppercase! 6 answers in 2 minutes!

Comment: I vote to close this question because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Comment: I can't believe it was a typo. I spent 2 hours searching and trying to solve it. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use **Key** not **key**

```
Console.WriteLine(Sneakers.Show(item.Key));
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like typo, it should be `item.Key`.

It is **K**ey not `key`

Answer (score 1):

`KeyValuePair` has a property named `Key`. Note the Pascal naming convention. You are using key, which is giving error.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Sneakers, double> item in collection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Sneakers.Show(item.Key));//HERE IS THE ERROR IN "key"
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

please pass K instead of k

item.**K**ey
:)

Answer (score 0):

Key should be started with upper case:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Sneakers, double> item in collection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Sneakers.Show(item.Key));//HERE IS THE ERROR IN "key"
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

class Sneakers is not marked as public